# Веб-дизайн для чайника

Tags: веб-программирование, книги, дизайн

Здравствуйте. С чего начать? Какие нужны программы? Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылки на здравые учебники и программы. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотели сенсея? :) скажите е-маил

Comment: :) сам себя ни похвалишь никто не похвалит

Comment: @Rules, не принимайте все так близко к сердцу. Я ведь всего лишь пошутил =)

Answer (score 4):

Человек спрашивает о дизайне, а вы ему про HTML.
Давайте конкретно списком.

- [#1](http://www.vira.ru/enc/design/interior/design_abc.html) Основы дизайна
- [#2](http://paintmaster.ru/tsvetovedenie.php.php) Основы цветоведения
- [#3.1](http://www.nundesign.com/st/35.html); [#3.2](http://www.nundesign.com/st/36.html); [#3.3](http://www.nundesign.com/st/37.html); [#3.4](http://www.nundesign.com/st/38.html); Основы веб-дизайна
- [#4](http://www.e-legion.ru/blog/internal-seminars/about-interface/) Основы проектирования интефейсов
- [#5.0->Inf](http://habrahabr.ru/hub/usability/) Юзабилити
- [#6](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148110/) Пример применения User Expirience
- Софт будет упоминаться по ходу статей.
- И разграничьте понятие дизайнера и верстальщика.

Answer (score 3):

Если под дизайном понимается разработка, то: [самоучитель HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/), затем CSS. 
Далее [все о PHP, MySQL и не только](http://php.su). Начальный уровень и общее представление получите.

Если дизайн в русском смысле слова, то гуглите видео-уроки по фотошопу и ищите книжку "Не заставляйте меня думать".

Answer (score 1):

Купите любую книгу про HTML. А лучше видео. Вод хороший вариант - Видеокурс по HTML (автор: Матковский Владислав).

Answer (score 1):

Круг "Не заставляйте меня думать" - о дизайне для веб-разработчиков. По техническим моментам - книжки издательства O'Reilly по интересующим технологиям.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Выучил html,в интернете полно онлайн уроков,и на YouTube тоже.
2. Выучил css(уроков также много,google и YouTubeвам в помощь),смотрел бы примеры,по ним бы изучал ,что-то новое,установил бы Notepad++.
3. Радовался бы и кодил)

Comment: 1) верстал, а не кодил (!) 
2) html и css учатся как бы одновременно

Answer (score 0):

Лично я начинал с обычного блокнота в Windows, без css... писал все на таблицах, было это дело пару лет назад (Не читал никаких учебников). До сих пор от таблиц избавиться не могу, сейчас лучше на div'ах все писать. Также же я пишу в данное время все в Notepad++, хоть и существуют такие инструменты как Dreamviewer, но они мне не по душе, наверно своей "накрученностью". Отладку кода js или html можно делать в браузере при просмотре страницы, или же проверять на валидность всякими инструментами. В общем советую просто понять принцип html разметки на примерах, можно начинать сразу с div, обычное размещение ячеек... столбцов. Далее по чуток изучать css, и добавлять стили к вашим столбцам, ячейкам. Далее можно javascript подучить, что не мало важно сейчас в наше время, я считаю сайт без js, это не сайт... И если честно, я вообще отношусь больше к back-end нежели front-end. Удачи в начинаниях!